# how to check if a cookie is set in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, cookies

I have made a cookie with my controller and this seems to work because if I check my resources in my developer tools it is there. But now I want to do actions with it in my view , but this doesn't seem to work , this is the code I used in my view:

```
@if (Cookie::get('cookiename') !== false)
    <p>cookie is set</p>
@else
    <p>cookie isn't set</p>
@endif
```

this is always returning 'true'

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

change

```
@if (Cookie::get('cookiename') !== false)
```

to

```
@if (Cookie::get('cookiename') !== null)
```

`null`, not `false` is returned when cookie isn't set: https://github.com/illuminate/http/blob/master/Request.php#L363

Comment: You can use `Cookie::has('cookiename')`, it will return boolean

Answer (score 15):

you can use this

```
if($request->hasCookie('cookie_name') != false)
```

Answer (score 7):

If you check out the Cookie class now you can use `Cookie::has('cookieName');`

```
class Cookie extends Facade
{
    /**
     * Determine if a cookie exists on the request.
     *
     * @param  string  $key
     * @return bool
     */
    public static function has($key)
    {
        return ! is_null(static::$app['request']->cookie($key, null));
    }

    // ...
```