# how to check if cookie exist in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I am trying to check a condition based on cookie but I am not able to do that.

```js
public function add_to_fav($product_id){

        $user_id = Cookie::has('u_id');
        if($user_id === 1){
            return "$is_already_added";
        } else{
            return "Login First";
        }


    }
```

Comment: ‘has’ return bool. Use ‘get’

Comment: I also try with that, But in **get**, If cookie was not present then how to check that?

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30199736/how-to-check-if-a-cookie-is-set-in-laravel) will help

Comment: Already checked this, No success

Comment: @Pooja if($user_id and $user_id == 1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just use the `isset($_COOKIE['u_id'])` and it works. Hope it worked for you :)

Comment: I know this will work, But I don't want to use constructions.